# What is the best way (performance) to make multi-language (Localization ) in mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I build my own cms using asp.net mvc 4, and I want make it multi language

I thought about make table in the database of those rows:
id, name, language, value

and then create a helper that check the correct language and then give the correct value of the name

```
@html.L("Newsletter.Title")
```

By the way, I hear about .resx files, so what will be the best way? (performance)
and is there a way to handle this files using the web instead of make it in the visual studio ?

I want add the ability to a user (who don't know what is .rest file, programming etc..) can add language and translate it in the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think resx files are great to localize "static" resources like buttons, navigation, etc, but not really dynamic content like the text on a page. But it always depends what your CMS is used for. Almost every CMS I know saves the data in a database. It's just more flexible than a .resx file.
But by all means, DON'T build your own CMS. Why would you wanna do that? There are tons of highly optimized CMS's out there.

Comment: I build my own cms for some reasons

Comment: I build my own cms for some reasons, first: I want to learn mvc and I want be a professional programmer (I'm just 24 old). 2) I like challenges and "work" with my brain, and . 3) I have more knowledge about how the cms is working and how to work with it. 4.) performance - I have a full control and knowing the purpose every file

Comment: Fair enough... Anyway, I would use tables.

Comment: do you have any guide or demonstration, so how can I do it with tables? especially the validation of the models

Comment: Hmm, not really. But there are two ways: Either you have a column for every language, or you have two field in every entry that groups them together and specifies the langauge. 
Not sure what you mean about validation?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance it's difficult to beat using resource files (.resx) as these are effectively XML files on the server - you don't have round trips to the database to fetch the localisation text.

The system uses keys with associated text values, and separate resx files for each supported locale.

In order to consume these strings you would use a strongly typed class like this-

```
<h1>@WebResources.Page_Title_String</h1>

<p>@WebResources.Intro_Paragraph</p>
```

This makes it easy to send your site for translation into different languages as all the strings are in one place and there are plenty of tools available to work with the files inside and outside of Visual Studio. It is even possible to [translate the file using Bing to give your translator a head start](http://www.guysmithferrier.com/post/2009/09/Automatically-Translating-resx-Files-Using-Microsoft-Translator.aspx).

As this is effectively an XML file, you can easily manipulate it with using Linq to XML to create a web interface to change the text if you want. I have seen at least a couple of commercial products which use this approach both for localisation and customisation of product text.

See [ASP.NET Web Page Resources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [How to: Create Resource Files for ASP.NET Web Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247246%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more details for Resource Files.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the best performance you would have to mix-up Resource Files (for static contents) and localized DB strings (for dynamic, CMS-created contents).

You can easily do that using the ResourceFiles + LocalizationRoute + LocalizationAttribute GlobalFilter approach which I [described in this guide](http://www.ryadel.com/en/setup-a-multi-language-website-using-asp-net-mvc/) on my blog.

**Localization Route:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultLocalized",
    url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    constraints: new { lang = @"(\w{2})|(\w{2}-\w{2})" },   // en or en-US
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

**Localization Attribute:**

```
public class LocalizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private string _DefaultLanguage = "en";
    public LocalizationAttribute(string defaultLanguage)
    {
        _DefaultLanguage = defaultLanguage;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string lang = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] ?? _DefaultLanguage;
        if (lang != _DefaultLanguage)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(String.Format("ERROR: Invalid language code '{0}'.", lang));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as you implemented that skeleton, your current Thread will have the proper localization set, so your localized Resource Files will be selected automatically. All you'll have to do is to query your DB for the most suitable localized content (if available) for the localization settings of the current thread.